# How do I compare a string in Flash to the name of a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible at all, but I'm trying to take a string in Flash and check to see if it is the same as the name of an already existing variable. Here is a piece of my code:

```
var randomNumber:int;
var randomNumberS:String;
var Mem1:String;
var Mem2:String;
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
randomnumberS = ("Mem" + String(randomNumber));
TGiven.text = [the randomnumberS string, except as either the variable name Mem1 or Mem2]
```

Is this a possible task, and if not, is there a better way to perform this task? It would be very useful as I plan on making many more variables that start with Mem with higher and higher numbers.

Comment: `"is there a better way to perform this task"` Probably yes. What task is it? What's the purpose behind doing this comparison?

Answer (score 0):

It would be optimal if the variables were a member of a [`class`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html) or [`Object`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html), to which you could evaluate whether they exist using [`hasOwnProperty()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29).

For example:

```
var obj:Object = {
    Mem1: "value1",
    Mem2: "value2"
};
```

You could test whether `obj` has a property by name:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty("Mem1");
```

Applying your example using random numbers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var randomNumber:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty("Mem" + randomNumber))
        trace("Mem" + randomNumber + " exists.");
    else
        trace("Mem" + randomNumber + " does not exist.");
}
```

You can also use the `in` keyword, such as:

```
"Mem1" in obj;
```

Using the same example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var randomNumber:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    if (("Mem" + randomNumber) in obj)
        trace("Mem" + randomNumber + " exists.");
    else
        trace("Mem" + randomNumber + " does not exist.");
}
```